# How can I access timemachine back ups from Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, backup

I can connect to my AirPort WiFi via my Linux machine but am trying to access time capsule backups I made when I had a MacBook Air. I have researched and found info on [airport-utils](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/airport-utils), but have had no luck.